# Splitting datas in three sets with balanced datas

Tags: r, loops, machine-learning, split

EDIT : OK so now I have my train, validation and test sets with rows belonging to patients in same groups. But, using a plot test, I see that the original imbalanced data from the original dataset (from the outcome LesionResponse, 1: 70% and 0 : 30%) is not very respected...Indeed, in the training datas, I have a nearly 55/45 repartition and it's not really welcomed for me. How can I do to correct this ?

```
summary(train$LesionResponse)
#   0   1
# 159 487
summary(validation$LesionResponse)
#  0   1
# 33 170
summary(test$LesionResponse)
#  0   1
# 77 126
```

Hi guys,
I have my dataset (here an exemple) and I must build a predictive model for an outcome : "LesionResponse".
So I have in a first time split my datas in train (60%), validation and test (20% each) sets.
I have a huge problem, many rows of my table belong to same patients...so in order to dodge bias, I must divide my datas and take into account the PatientIDs...
I am here stuck because I don't know how to split my datas in three and keep the rows belonging to same patients together.

Here is my code :

```
structure(list(PatientID = c("P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P2", "P3", "P3", "P4", "P5", 
"P5", "P6"), LesionResponse = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), pyrad_tum_original_shape_LeastAxisLength = c(19.7842995242803, 
    15.0703960571122, 21.0652247652897, 11.804125918871, 27.3980336338908, 
    17.0584330264122, 4.90406343942677, 4.78480430022189, 6.2170232078547, 
    5.96309532740722, 5.30141540007441), pyrad_tum_original_shape_Sphericity = c(0.652056853392657, 
    0.773719977240238, 0.723869070051882, 0.715122964970338, 
    0.70796498824535, 0.811937882810929, 0.836458991713367, 0.863337931630415, 
    0.851654860256904, 0.746212862162174), pyrad_tum_log.sigma.5.0.mm.3D_firstorder_Skewness = c(0.367453961973625, 
    0.117673346718817, 0.0992025164349288, -0.174029385779302, 
    -0.863570016875989, -0.8482193060411, -0.425424618080682, 
    -0.492420174157913, 0.0105111292451967, 0.249865833210199), pyrad_tum_log.sigma.5.0.mm.3D_glcm_Contrast = c(0.376932105256115, 
    0.54885738172596, 0.267158344601612, 2.90094719958076, 0.322424096161189, 
    0.221356030145403, 1.90012334870722, 0.971638740404501, 0.31547550396399, 
    0.653999340294952), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_GrayLevelNonUniformityNormalized = c(0.154973213866752, 
    0.176128379241556, 0.171129002059539, 0.218343919352019, 
    0.345985943932352, 0.164905080489496, 0.104536489151874, 
    0.1280276816609, 0.137912385073012, 0.133420904484894), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_LargeAreaEmphasis = c(27390.2818110851, 
    11327.7931034483, 51566.7948885976, 7261.68702290076, 340383.536555142, 
    22724.7792207792, 45.974358974359, 142.588235294118, 266.744186046512, 
    1073.45205479452), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_LargeAreaLowGrayLevelEmphasis = c(677.011907073653, 
    275.281153810458, 582.131636238695, 173.747506476692, 6140.73990175018, 
    558.277670638306, 1.81042257642817, 4.55724031114589, 6.51794350173746, 
    19.144924585586), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_SizeZoneNonUniformityNormalized = c(0.411899490603372, 
    0.339216399209913, 0.425584323452468, 0.355165782879786, 
    0.294934042125209, 0.339208410636982, 0.351742274819198, 
    0.394463667820069, 0.360735532720389, 0.36911240382811)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

i was thinking about a loop who would split a `unique(PatientID)` dataset in three with 60% in the train set, and if there is no balanced outcome in the sets, to do it again and again. I was thinking more of an interval to solve it...
How would you do guys ?

Answer (score 2):

***Edit*** I misunderstood how you wished to handle PatientIDs. The original answer is at the bottom, however note stratification will aim to put equivalent proportions of each PatientID in each split. You should use the `group_` splitting function indicated by @Rui Barradas.

```r
library(tidymodels)

set.seed(217)
df_split <- group_initial_split(df, PatientID, prop = 4/5)
df_training <- training(df_split)
df_testing <- testing(df_split)
df_validation <- group_validation_split(df_training, PatientID, prop = 3/4)
```

*Original reply*
In the `tidymodels` framework you can opt to stratify the sampling using your `PatientID` variable. The resulting resamples will have equivalent proportions.

To create your desired splits you could first split the data 80:20 training:testing, then split the training set 75:25 into training:validation.

```r
library(tidymodels)

set.seed(217)
df_split <- initial_split(df, prop = 4/5, strata = PatientID)
df_training <- training(df_split)
df_testing <- testing(df_split)
df_validation <- validation_split(df_training, prop = 3/4, strata = PatientID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with package `rsample`.
First split in `test` and other data (named `train` in the code below) keeping all `PatientID` in the same subsets, then split `train`.

```r
library(rsample)

set.seed(2023)
g <- group_initial_split(df1, group = PatientID, prop = 0.8)
train <- training(g)
test <- testing(g)
g <- group_initial_split(train, group = PatientID, prop = 3/4)
train <- training(g)
validation <- testing(g)

# check data split proportions
df_list <- list(train = train, validation = validation, test = test)
sapply(df_list, nrow)
#>      train validation       test 
#>        600        199        201

# this shows that all groups belong to one subset only
lapply(df_list, \(x) unique(x[[1]]))
#> $train
#> [1] "P5"  "P9"  "P8"  "P3"  "P10" "P4" 
#> 
#> $validation
#> [1] "P2" "P7"
#> 
#> $test
#> [1] "P1" "P6"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Test data

```r
set.seed(2023)
p <- sprintf("P%d", 1:10)
n <- 1e3
df1 <- data.frame(
  PatientID = sample(p, n, TRUE),
  x = rnorm(n)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much it works very well. I just checked between train et test the function inner_join and there is no common datas !!

Comment: But I don't understand the second part where you create the test data...and when I want to check the rows with lapply(df_list, \(x) unique(x[[1]])), i get an error message : Error: unexpected input in "lapply(df_list, \"

Comment: @NDe The error comes from the new lambda function introduced in R 4.1, ```\(x)```, use `function(x)` instead. (Time to update R?) As for the test data, it comes from the first split with proportions 0.8/0.2. Then the 1st train data set is in its turn split between train and validation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a one-liner that `sample`s one of `1:3` for unique patient IDs and `split`s `df` by that.

```
set.seed(42)
res <- split(df, with(df, ave(id, id, FUN=\(x) sample.int(3, 1, prob=c(.6, .2, .2)))))
```

*Tests:*

```
## test proportions (should approx. be [.6, .2, .2])
proportions(sapply(res, \(x) length(unique(x$id)))) |> round(2)
#    1    2    3 
# 0.53 0.25 0.22 

## test uniqueness
stopifnot(length(Reduce(intersect, lapply(res, `[[`, 'id'))) == 0)
```

### Update

To get more stable proportions, we could use fixed group sizes by `rep`eating `1:3` by vector `p`.

```
len <- length(u <- unique(df$id))
p1 <- c(.2, .2)
rlp <- round(len*p1)
p <- c(len - sum(rlp), rlp)
set.seed(42)
a <- setNames(rep.int(1:3, p), sample(u))

res <- split(df, a[match(df$id, names(a))])  ## this line splits the df

proportions(sapply(res, \(x) length(unique(x$id))))
#   1   2   3 
# 0.6 0.2 0.2 

## test uniqueness
stopifnot(length(Reduce(intersect, lapply(res, `[[`, 'id'))) == 0)
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 200; np <- 100
df <- data.frame(id=paste0('P', as.integer(as.factor(sort(sample.int(np, n, replace=TRUE))))),
                 les=sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE),
                 pyr=runif(n))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ! but I am a beginner in R, and I don't understand all the code. What is "id" in `ave` ? When I substitute by `PatientID` (the exact name of the feature), I have an error message...

Comment: @NDe I used the example `df` shown at the bottom of my answer, to have more patients. Replace `ìd` by `PatientID` to adapt the code to your data (I thought that might be obvious).

Comment: I understood^^ but when I switch for PatientID I have the same problem : `Error: unexpected input in "res <- split(df, with(df, ave(PatientID, PatientID, FUN=\"`

Comment: @NDe Update your R or use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`.

Comment: ok nice ! thank you very much, do you know how to have a conservation of the outcome imbalanced through the sets obtained ? I see that some sets have far more outcome 1 than 0 (LesionResponse). Do I must use the Strata argument ?

Comment: In the original datas, I have a proportion of 60-70/30-40% 1/0, and in some sets obtained, I have like a huge disproportion 9/1 for example